# JavaScript cannot display

Tags: javascript-objects

I am a newbie.  Please tell what is wrong with the following JavaScript, which cannot display function, many thanks.

```
 var car = {
   size: "small",
   color: "red",
   show: function() {
   console.log("This is my " + car.size);
   }
 };

 show();
```

Comment: Use `car.show()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to Use car.show()
Try it and then Reply me in cmnts what is your output

`var car = {
        size: "small",
       color: "red",
       show: function() {
       console.log("This is my " + car.size);
       }
       };
        car.show(); // reffer to object first and then to your func`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var car = {
     size: "small",
  color: "red",
   show: function() {
   console.log("This is my " + car.size);
   }
  };

 car.show();// You should call like this
```